# Splunk compare two rex queries from different source

Tags: splunk, splunk-query, rex

I have two queries...

**(1)** submit log query:

```
index=xxx_prod host="foo.org" 5032 submit | rex "id=PO:(?<PO>\d*)" | dedup PO | table PO _time
```

**(2)** saved log query:

```
index=xxx_prod host="bar.org" | rex "savePO.*POId=(?<PO>\d*).*\"responseCode\":200" | dedup PO | table PO _time
```

I want to compare both `PO` and `timestamp` (from _time field) results from different services one is a submit event, another one is a save event. and I want to show it as the following table

```
   PO    | submit_date             | save_date               | elapse_time_min | isSave   
 1000001 | 2020-01-18 02:09:49.022 | 2020-01-18 02:51:51q289 | 41              | true
 1000002 | 2020-01-18 03:18:25.780 | 2020-01-18 03:59:08.695 | 49              | true
 1000003 | 2020-01-18 03:18:25.780 |                         |                 | false
```

Answer (score 0):

You will want to look at the [transaction](https://docs.splunk.com/Documentation/Splunk/8.0.1/SearchReference/Transaction) command, which helps to join events based on a field, in your case, `PO`

```
(index=xxx_prod host="foo.org" 5032 submit) OR (index=xxx_prod host="bar.org") | rex "id=PO:(?<PO>\d*)" | rex "savePO.*POId=(?<PO>\d*).*\"responseCode\":200" | transaction keeporphans=true PO | eval save_date = _time + duration | convert ctime(save_date) | table _time save_date duration
```

You will need to check the `rex` commands extract properly, and the `transaction` command above is using `keeporphans`, which keeps submit events that don't have a matching save event.

Answer (score 0):

You can use left join on field `PO` in this case.

```
index=xxx_prod host="foo.org" 5032 submit | rex "id=PO:(?<PO>\d*)" | dedup PO | table PO _time
|rename _time as submit_date
|join type=left PO
[search index=xxx_prod host="bar.org" | rex "savePO.*POId=(?<PO>\d*).*\"responseCode\":200" | dedup PO | table PO _time
|rename _time as save_date]
|eval elapse_time_min=round((save_date-submit_date)/60),0)
|eval isSave=if(isnull(save_date),"false","true")
|eval save_date=strftime(save_date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Q")
|eval submit_date=strftime(submit_date,"%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%Q")
```